# PyGTK: Doubleclick on CellRenderer

Tags: python, pygtk, cellrenderer, double-click

In my PyGTK application I currently use 'editable' to make cells editable. But since my cell contents sometimes are really really large I want to ask the user for changes in a new window when he doubleclicks on a cell. But I could not find out how to hook on double-clicks on specific cellrenderers - I don't want to edit the whole row and I also don't want to set this callback for the whole row, only for columns where too long content can occur. How can I do this with CellRendererText() or something similar.

My currently cell-generating code is:

```
cols[i] = gtk.TreeViewColumn(coltitle)
cells[i] = gtk.CellRendererText()
cols[i].pack_start(cells[i])
cols[i].add_attribute(cells[i], 'text', i)
cols[i].set_sizing(gtk.TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED)
cols[i].set_fixed_width(100)
cells[i].set_property('editable', True)
cells[i].connect('edited', self.edited, (i, ls))
cols[i].set_resizable(True)
mytreeview.append_column(cols[i])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is not possible directly.  However, you can connect to `button-press-event` on the `gtk.TreeView`.  Then, when `event.type` equals to `gtk.gdk._2BUTTON_PRESS`, convert `x` and `y` to tree location using `gtk.TreeView.get_path_at_pos()`.  This will return both a tree path indicating the row and `gtk.TreeViewColumn` object on which the click was made.

Comment: Very dirty :-D - but, if its the only possibility… ;-)